# FckEditor converts nbsp; to some strange characters?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, fckeditor

I have pasted some text to fckeditor and the spaces become `&nbsp` thats ok, but when I open the same content the same `&nbsp` becomes some strange character (like a revers question mark `�`). I have tried to change FCKConfig.FillEmptyBlocks to false and true but this still did not help. I use fckeditor version 2.6.3, I use this editor in codeigniter php.

Comment: Are your character sets consistent?

Comment: Where do you open the content?

Comment: I use utf-8 character set and I open the content in my own cms written with codeigniter framework.

Comment: Is the text coming out of a MySQL table? If so, make sure the column holding the text is also using utf-8. I've had many times where if the database column was on a different character set strange things occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I turn off global_xss_filtering by setting

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

and Setting xss_clean on fields that require it.

or

Change your character set encoding. See what FckEditor is using.

I also found this:

1.- in xhtml files:

2.- in MySQL database: DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

3.- FCKeditor requires a change in the configuration file: fckconfig.js in line 65 true for false in the following instruction:

FCKConfig.IncludeLatinEntities = false ; /* This way worked fine for Spanish */

See this link: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/FCK-UTF-8-encoding-FCKeditor-not-working-special-charac

Maybe that could fix your problem if you have that turned on.